# Python error message

Tags: python

How can I fix this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tony\Desktop\Python\4.py", line 64, in 
    print "YOU PAY: $",(pc-total)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

Comment: Not only is this a programming question, you are running the program on Windows. Wrong site.

Answer (score 5):

One of the two, `pc` or `total`, is a float and the other a string.

As python is strongly typed you would need to cast the string to a float, e.g.:

```
print "YOU PAY $",(float(pc) - total)
```